# Group data by unique id, year

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm putting together data from multiple csv files, where the columns/rows are all the same except they're from different years. I want to collate them and put them in the following format, where each observation would be grouped by a unique id and a year column showing the year each data point was recorded:

```
    id      year         foo          bar
100654      2010       0.043        0.045
            2011       0.635        0.343
            2012       0.523        0.325
            2013       0.278        0.623
            2014       0.256        0.234
100784      2010       0.345        0.263
            2011       0.452        0.267
            2012       0.635        0.021
            2013       0.836        0.639
            2014       0.043        0.209
```

Tried doing this by assigning the year to a new column in the dataframe as I read it in, so that when I concatenate everything together I'll be able to keep track of what year each observation is from:

```py
# concatenate all dataframes and group by institution
df_list = []

for key, value in data_by_year.items():
    data_by_year[key]["school_year"] = key
    df_list.append(data_by_year[key])

data = pd.concat(df_list, join="inner")
grouped_data = data.groupby(by=["id", "school_year"])
```

But all I get is this, which is pretty much identical to what I would've gotten if I'd just stacked each dataframe one-by-one on top of the other (except for the `school_year` column I added):

```
            id  region_id                                               name  \
0       100654        5.0                           Alabama A & M University   
1       100663        5.0                University of Alabama at Birmingham   
2       100690        5.0                                 Amridge University   
3       100706        5.0                University of Alabama in Huntsville   
4       100724        5.0                           Alabama State University
```

Tried using `pd.melt()` as well. That didn't work either, since it keeps none of the other columns in the dataframe except for the two I specified:

```py
# concatenate all dataframes and group by institution
df_list = []

for key, value in data_by_year.items():
    data_by_year[key]["school_year"] = key
    df_list.append(data_by_year[key])

data = pd.concat(df_list, join="inner")
grouped_data = data.melt(id_vars=["id"], value_vars=["school_year"])
```

```
        id     variable  value
0   100654  school_year  10_11
1   100663  school_year  10_11
2   100690  school_year  10_11
3   100706  school_year  10_11
4   100724  school_year  10_11
5   100751  school_year  10_11
```

What can I do differently? In both cases, changing the join type in the `pd.concat()` method to `outer` changes nothing.

Comment: `data = pd.concat(df_list, join="inner").set_index(['id','year']).sort_index()`?

Comment: Can you show your initial dataframe?

Comment: `df.set_index(['id','year'])`?

Comment: @QuangHoang: that did the trick, thank you!